# Is this string encoded

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine, exploit

I've got a client with a website that uses codeignite and expression engine,

we've got a certain IP address that seems to be crawling through every page link and appending it with the following string and its making the cpu usage go like crazy! the file itself doesnt actually exist so I assume its somebody trying to exploit it.

```
jl1t6ZrqxJydBuZjJPTjHXNReaeo/kW/rio23/22hzp9CoSkWDSzpjdEpT30ZMub1umPwGV02ZIa8cdz8jfbqCIg1l0d7ymYZpPzskTzHeeckbkiI/qbo5GcoEyuqNzj85CsV5ja0qpf26srnUUPlE8Ta6Y28/BQI2n04r1Q9RBk+MyHguj6OgHoqzCpEifYb0Bf6xr5TtSxuZz+LFTTFWWWR66Br+r6KTQjXIMYXoqS+AGOmzQATKxW+OhZxJOvvNFF2xF4gp2Vhu79A25d8Y/4Q6JwmCowSXaZDiR7DEYgt3wmic2r3XRlvchEMw0VG+ilR4taaT8iS7U9PzXAk9wsxbk2YMkSpW+xMxl3YNDLO7Z+PQHFLFhK4VUVV2oMRF1FCHetFfpqTonRpAW5o8zTxWS/K3YXmHQj5jB0roM=/
```

that so any normal address for instance, /site/contact-us/ would be appended to

```
/site/contact-us/jl1t6zrqx......etc
```

does anybody recon that that could be something encoded or what do you think could be going on?

Many Thanks

Comment: Try posting this here as well: http://expressionengine.com/forums/

Comment: My guess is an evil doer probing for a buffer overflow. If you are concerned you might consider installing Fail2ban which allows you to create rules to detect and take action on a variety of attacks.

Comment: People probing for buffer overflows usually go for easy strings like 'AAAAAAAAAAA...', not random base-64 encoded gibberish.

Comment: It does decode as base64 into exactly 320 bytes (if you leave off the trailing slash).

Answer (score 0):

You should take up the issue with the host to block the IP, and also make sure they have request limits in place.

As was stated above, you should also try other forms of software that are at a lower level (web server/network) in the process to detect and deter these requests from happening.

Comment: Not really answering the question at hand, was interested in the string not protection from it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, if it's affecting the CPU, then it is a problem. In my book, anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem ofc, just not the answer to the question thats all I was getting at :)